# radio option with value to be checked by default

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, radio-button

I have a radio option list as shown below . I want the first option to be selected by default on first render , but it is not giving the desired output:

```
<label class="radio normalFontWeight">
                <input type="radio" name="Criteria" data-ng-value="EVERYONE_REVIEWED" data-ng-model="stage.completionRule" checked="checked"> 
                option 1
</label>                                              
<label class="radio normalFontWeight">
                    <input type="radio" name="Criteria" data-ng-value="HAS_MIN_REVIEWS" data-ng-model="stage.completionRule"> 
                    option 2
    </label>
```

i have tried with both `checked="checked"`  &&  `checked`  but was not successful , as on first render both of the options r unselected

Comment: Your code works as intended -> https://jsfiddle.net/279qczoh/ . Can you reproduce this problem in a code snippet ?

Comment: It's working fine

Comment: @MihaiT thanks for the feedbak but its not working . however I have figured out the problem: The ng-model value needs to be initialized with corresponding input value of radio button to be checked by default i.e. [ stage.completionRule = "EVERYONE_REVIEWED" ]

Comment: well we couldn't figure that out with the amount of code and context you gave us. Next time before posting a question check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and give more context to your problem

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the problem: 
The ng-model value needs to be initialized with corresponding input value of radio button to be checked by default i.e. in my case `stage.completionRule = "EVERYONE_REVIEWED"`